# How can I block all webpages of a given website on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line

I wish to block all webpages of a given website, for example blocking all YouTube webpages, using linux as opposed to a browser extension like BlockSite(which can be disabled quite easily).

I have tried using the `$ sudo gedit /etc/hosts` and then using the method outlined [here](https://bytenbit.com/how-to-block-websites-on-windows-ubuntu-macintosh/) but this merely results in the URL "youtube.com" being blocked rather than all webpages of YouTube being blocked.

How can I get browser extension like funtionality using the command line?

Answer (score 0):

Editing /etc/hosts works for me.
There are maybe two points to consider to have it working:

- The exact line to write in hosts is `127.0.0.1       www.youtube.com`. If I don't specify "www." the youtube.com page in indeed blocked, but the rest of Youtube can still be accessed.
- Once you've edited (and saved !) your hosts file, you have to restart the web browser.